# Enable ESlint in vendor folder - Laravel VueJs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, phpstorm, eslint

How to enable eslint in Laravel vendor folder?

The main development takes place within vendor folder. Our project based on Laravel packages.
I have enabled and configure eslint in the "root" project and it works fine. Currently work in PHPStorm and use eslint in it.

*.eslintrc.json*

```
{
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:vue/essential",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "vue",
        "prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": "warn"
    }
}
```

*.prettierrc.json*

```
{
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": true
}
```

resources/js/components/App.vue - Fix ESlint Problems:

[image: resources/js/components/App.vue - Fix ESlint Problems]

But in vendor package it doesn't.

vendor\testpackage\uitest01\recources\js\components\TestTwoComponent.vue - Fix ESlint Problems isn't presented:

[image: vendor\testpackage\uitest01\recources\js\components\TestTwoComponent.vue - Fix ESlint Problems isn't presented]

Any ideas how enable it?
Thank you!

Comment: Would be interesting to see your config file.

Comment: @Aer0
It's very basic:
`{
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:vue/essential",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "vue",
        "prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": "warn"
    }
}`
Plus prettier: "trailingComma": "es5", "tabWidth": 4...

Comment: Would you mind putting that into your question please? That's the place where it belongs to. Also it's easier to read there.

Comment: Are you sure the directory isn't being ignore anywhere like in `.eslintignore` or `.gitignore`? It should be. It's really not a good idea to modify files in the vendor directory. It will be overwritten any time you want to upgrade your dependencies. Rather fork the packages you want to modify.

Comment: @DelenaMalan
I have no `.eslintignore` but I have `.gitignore`... I'm not sure that is connected with eslint. But it's good idea (generally), to do somthng with `.gitignore` in this case :)
I'm working on my own package.
Thank you )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel projects, vendor packages are auto-added to PHP Include paths and thus are treated as libraries. But inspections are not enabled in library files, and linter errors are not reported for them. Try removing your package from **Include Path** list in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP**:

[image]

and then un-exclude the `vendor/testpackage/uitest01` folder. This should help:

[image]

**Remove packages as libraries permanently:**

In **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Composer**, try disabling **Add packages as libraries** to avoid auto-adding packages to **Include path** (you will then need to add the packages you'd like being treated as libraries manually)

Comment: Almost there :) Unfortunately after restart of `PHPStorm`, the setting is resetting :( ...and `ESlinter` still doesn't work, only `prettier`.
I tried to make /.idea/php.xml file read only, it works with small error: 
  `Could not save project: Unable to save project files. Please ensure project files are writable and you have permissions to modify them. Try to save project again.`

Comment: in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Composer**, try disabling **Add packages as libraries** to avoid auto-adding packages to **Include path** (you will then need to add the packages you'd like being treated as libraries manually)

Comment: Great! Thank you! This is what I need :)
I'm using PHPStorm as big nice code editor, and doing all composer things from external cli. I don't care if IDE know nothing about composer and libraries :)
And ESlint now works, good!